# How do I limit the number of clicks on a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, click, limit

I need to display the button `Hour`, 2 numbers in `big font` 0:0, and a button `Minute`.

The first number represents the hour, the second number represents the minute.

Whenever the user clicks the `Hour` button, the first number is increased by `1`, so that it goes
`like 0, 1, 2, 3, …, 23.`

If the hour number is `23` and the user clicks the hour button then the
number goes back to `0`.

Similarly, whenever the user clicks the “Minute” button, the second number is increased by `1`, so
that it goes like `0, 1, 2, 3, …, 59`. If the minute number is `59` and the user clicks the minute button
then the number goes back to `0`.

Here's what I have done so far.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <button onclick="displaycount()">Hour </button>
</td>
<td>
  <p id="carrier"> 0 </p>
</td>
<td>
  :
</td>
<td>
  <p id="carrier2"> 0 </p>
</td>
<td>
  <button onclick="displaycount2()">Minute </button>
</td>


</tr>
</table>

<script>
var count =(function() {
var counter = 0;
return function() {return counter +=1;}
})();

var count2 =(function() {
var counter = 0;
return function() {return counter +=1;}
})();

function displaycount(){
document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = count();
}

function displaycount2(){
document.getElementById("carrier2").innerHTML = count2();
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's an interesting style; here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4ysLwf8t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulus `(%)` to reset the counter back to 0 for hours and minutes:

```js
var count = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() {
      return counter = (counter + 1) % 24;
    }
  })();

var count2 = (function() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function() {
    return counter = (counter + 1) % 60;
  }
})();

function displaycount() {
  document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = count();
}

function displaycount2() {
  document.getElementById("carrier2").innerHTML = count2();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="displaycount()">Hour </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="carrier"> 0 </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      :
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="carrier2"> 0 </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="displaycount2()">Minute </button>
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>
```